# Oracle Error: Not a valid function or procedure name

Tags: oracle, function

I'm having some major issues trying to get some functions up and running in Oracle 11.2.0.1.0

This function below is not complete - but at this point I'm just trying to get it to compile/execute/call without any issues.

Here's what I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "MYTABLE"."TMP_TEST" return number
is 
f_qtr (4,0);

begin

UPDATE "MYTABLE".FOO  SET BAR = 555
where FOOBAR = 3;
f_qtr: =1;
return (f_qtr);
```

Then I log into SQL Plus and do the following

```
call MYTABLE.TMP_TEST;
```

And I get the following back

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use a variable like:

```
var a number
exec :a := TMP_TEST
print a
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do :-

```
select TMP_TEST from dual;
```

or use a SELECT ... INTO also if you want to save the output in a variable....